# How do you hide secret keys in code?

Tags: encryption, obfuscation

I've wondered for some time how some software hides secret keys in such a way that they can't be trivially discovered. Just a few examples:

- DVD Player Software hides CSS keys
- Software with serial numbers/registration codes hides keys/hashes used to validate the serial numbers

Obviously, these programs do something more than just have the key in a byte[], as that would make it easy to steal their keys and generate your own serial numbers, etc.

What sorts of strategies are used to hide these keys so that they can't be found easily?

Comment: But how does Adobe do it with Photoshop for example?

Comment: One word: unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The reasons those secret keys were so easily discovered is because they were hidden in software.

Avoid hiding secrets in software at all cost - obfuscation will only get you so far.  Ask yourself this:  How well can I hide a key in software from someone with full access to the disassembly, user mode and kernel mode debuggers, and no day job?  It's only a matter of time before it gets cracked.

Comment: Does this answer the question?

Comment: As you said, "It's only a matter of time before it gets cracked". So this is a reason why this strategie might be accpebtable considering that this key will expire sooner that hardware protected keys.

Answer (score 13):

You just hide the key somewhere, and decrypt it when you need it. Using the key "securely" is the complicated part. Crackers might set a breakpoint to the place where you use the decrypted key and dump it. They might scan your code for patterns which show that you are using a known crypto algorithm (most algorithms have precalculated tables). etc etc.

That's why you need to make the whole software executable hard to analyze. For this you use executable packers, running code in a virtual machine, integrity checks etc. All this is to slow down debugging and modifying your code.

As most people here point out you can't stop anyone, just slow them down. I'd go to a cracker forum and ask there for suggestions about key hiding problematics. They are most likely helpful if you ask nicely.

ps. Public key crypto won't hide the key any better, but it might make it harder (or theoretically impossible) to make a key generator, if you're doing a licensing scheme.

Answer (score 6):

The bottom line is, you can't.  See any other comment here for the reasons why.  Even encryption software like PGP/GPG stores the keys in a file, and then stridently urges those files to be kept on a flash drive in a safe, or something else secure.  Keys stored as part of executable code will be discovered.

In fact, if you're trying to encrypt anything on a client machine that will be decrypted by the client as part of normal operations, that is also a fool's errand.  The client machines are inherently insecure, and you can't control what they're going to be able to do to your data.

If you're trying to authenticate, instead, look at Internet based authentication with logins to a server, or some kind of generated KeyCode that is used to validate the software.

Secret keys as part of a Public-Private Keypair should be kept in data files that can be secured.  Symmetric keys should be generated on the fly as Session Keys, then discarded.  Always assume that anyone who has a Secret or Session key on their computer will be able to discover it, and use it against your intentions.

Read "[Applied Cryptography](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471117099)" by Bruce Schneier for more information.

Comment: The statement "Even encryption software like PGP/GPG stores the keys in a file" is misleading.  PGP encrypts those keys using a passphrase known only to the user.  PGP also uses secure memory for keys ensuring that they are never cached to the HD and PGP goes through great lengths to make it difficult to find a key using memory inspection.  If I could down mod this answer I would.

Comment: My point was that there is no secret data stored in the source code.  It is up to the user to secure their own secret keys.  Even with a passphrase on the secret keys, once a malicious party has access to the secret key file, it's game over.  Storing a secret key anywhere accessable to anyone but a trusted party will result in pain, whether that's the exe, RAM, or a file.

Answer (score 5):

You can't hide a key forever. But you can sure make it hard to find. Some approaches are to encrypt the key in memory, keep multiple copies (perhaps encrypted differently) that are checked against each other, leave dummy copies to be accessed, store the key in some bizarre format, etc. None of them will work if somebody really wants your key, but you can at least dissuade a casual/inexperienced attacker.

Comment: It typically isn't all that hard for people to find even hidden keys if they are determined to do so.

Answer (score 3):

You don't always need a key to validate a license.

But ignoring that fact, your key can also be the result of another function. You don't actually store a specific key value, instead you have a function that generates the key on the fly (always the same result). Although not impossible, it's much harder to find since you're no longer looking for a value, but you have to figure out it's an equation.

Comment: Waste of time. Any cracker will simply take the result of the function straight out of memory (or maybe just copy the entire function into his keygen). It's not a homework assignment; he just has to get the right answer, without needing to show his work

Answer (score 1):

When we started developing our software, we've created a dated license file. Then, we realized, that not too many people are even interested in buying our software. Then, we decided to give it away for free. A lot more people started to care at least trying our masterpiece. Finally, we've open sourced our software. A lot more users started using it. Now we just hope that a small number of these users might turn into paying customers (i.e. buying prod. support or asking for customization).

The bottom line is, if someone wants to crack your software, he/she'll do it anyway. Is it really worth it to waste your time trying to protect it with this hidden secret key?

Comment: The whole process of your business seems quite backwards and ad-hoc.

Comment: This business model valid for only certain (trivial) softwares.

Answer (score 1):

If you can afford it, the best is to store the private key in a cryptographic USB token. The key is write only, ie you can set it but not read it. The token does the cryptographic operations internally, in its hardware. It becomes very complicated to retrieve the key (if the token has no known vulnerability, which is not the case with older ones).

Comment: This kind of protection is only one leve up than software. You can replicate USB key using any memory dumping. Case you go ahead and try to check users online users by given key id, then you may patch also network. There's no true way to protect code. The best way to do it, is to dissapoint people trying to crack it, and making a renewal of the system in a regular basis. The little timeframe between you and the one who can crack you is your only friend here.

Comment: The best way to dissapoint users to use cracked software, is being the first to release a crack, and putting LOT OF viruses on it. Doing that you can dissapoint someone more imporant than the one who can crack you ---> the user that wanna use your software. Make an affordable pricing plan and you'll success much more than hidding keys.

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://godbolt.org/ to look at the assembly and see, there are a couple things you can do to make it more difficult. First is to hide the symbols (so `checkSecret()` isn't so obvious), and the second to use a function to generate the key/password. The idea is that it will take longer to find the part of the code that will lead to bypassing any security, so also not calling it from the `main` function is probably a good idea.

Looking at two approaches:

1. an explicitly declared password
2. a function that generates the password

Here's an example of the first:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

string secretKey = "fdasfdasfydsafhidljj3r32R#@f";

bool securityCheck(string key){
    if(key==secretKey) cout << "Success!" << endl;
    return key==secretKey;
}

int main(){
    securityCheck(secretKey);
}
```

As you can see more clearly on https://godbolt.org/, this creates the following assembly (with gcc 11.2):

```
secretKey[abi:cxx11]:
        .zero   32
.LC0:
        .string "Success!"
securityCheck(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >):
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 16
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], rdi
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
        mov     esi, OFFSET FLAT:secretKey[abi:cxx11]
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    __gnu_cxx::__enable_if<std::__is_char<char>::__value, bool>::__type std::operator==<char>(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)
        test    al, al
        je      .L16
        mov     esi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZSt4cout
        call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)
        mov     esi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& (*)(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&))
.L16:
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
        mov     esi, OFFSET FLAT:secretKey[abi:cxx11]
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    __gnu_cxx::__enable_if<std::__is_char<char>::__value, bool>::__type std::operator==<char>(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)
        leave
        ret
main:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        push    rbx
        sub     rsp, 40
        lea     rax, [rbp-48]
        mov     esi, OFFSET FLAT:secretKey[abi:cxx11]
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) [complete object constructor]
        lea     rax, [rbp-48]
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    securityCheck(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)
        lea     rax, [rbp-48]
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string() [complete object destructor]
        mov     eax, 0
        jmp     .L22
        mov     rbx, rax
        lea     rax, [rbp-48]
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string() [complete object destructor]
        mov     rax, rbx
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    _Unwind_Resume
.L22:
        mov     rbx, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
        leave
        ret
.LC1:
        .string "basic_string::_M_construct null not valid"

.LC2:
        .string "fdasfdasfydsafhidljj3r32R#@f"
__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int):
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        push    rbx
        sub     rsp, 40
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-36], edi
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-40], esi
        cmp     DWORD PTR [rbp-36], 1
        jne     .L58
        cmp     DWORD PTR [rbp-40], 65535
        jne     .L58
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZStL8__ioinit
        call    std::ios_base::Init::Init() [complete object constructor]
        mov     edx, OFFSET FLAT:__dso_handle
        mov     esi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZStL8__ioinit
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev
        call    __cxa_atexit
        lea     rax, [rbp-17]
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    std::allocator<char>::allocator() [complete object constructor]
        lea     rax, [rbp-17]
        mov     rdx, rax
        mov     esi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC2
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:secretKey[abi:cxx11]
        call    std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string<std::allocator<char> >(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&)
        lea     rax, [rbp-17]
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    std::allocator<char>::~allocator() [complete object destructor]
        mov     edx, OFFSET FLAT:__dso_handle
        mov     esi, OFFSET FLAT:secretKey[abi:cxx11]
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string() [complete object destructor]
        call    __cxa_atexit
        jmp     .L58
        mov     rbx, rax
        lea     rax, [rbp-17]
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    std::allocator<char>::~allocator() [complete object destructor]
        mov     rax, rbx
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    _Unwind_Resume
.L58:
        mov     rbx, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
        leave
        ret
_GLOBAL__sub_I_secretKey[abi:cxx11]:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     esi, 65535
        mov     edi, 1
        call    __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

You can see that the `secretKey` is plainly visible, and the function names are as well.

Here's a second example:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

string getSecretKey(){
    srand(100);
    string chars = "qwertyuioplkjhgfdsazxcvbnm123456789";
    string result = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i){
        result += chars[rand()%chars.size()];
    }
    return result;
}

string secretKey = getSecretKey();

bool securityCheck(string key){
    if(key==secretKey) cout << "Success!" << endl;
    return key==secretKey;
}

int main(){
    securityCheck(secretKey);
}
```

This produces the following assembly:

```
.LC0:
        .string "qwertyuioplkjhgfdsazxcvbnm123456789"
.LC1:
        .string ""
getSecretKey[abi:cxx11]():
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        push    rbx
        sub     rsp, 72
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-72], rdi
        mov     edi, 100
        call    srand
        lea     rax, [rbp-22]
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    std::allocator<char>::allocator() [complete object constructor]
        lea     rdx, [rbp-22]
        lea     rax, [rbp-64]
        mov     esi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string<std::allocator<char> >(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&)
        lea     rax, [rbp-22]
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    std::allocator<char>::~allocator() [complete object destructor]
        lea     rax, [rbp-21]
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    std::allocator<char>::allocator() [complete object constructor]
        lea     rdx, [rbp-21]
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-72]
        mov     esi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC1
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string<std::allocator<char> >(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&)
        lea     rax, [rbp-21]
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    std::allocator<char>::~allocator() [complete object destructor]
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-20], 0
        jmp     .L16
.L17:
        call    rand
        movsx   rbx, eax
        lea     rax, [rbp-64]
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::size() const
        mov     rcx, rax
        mov     rax, rbx
        mov     edx, 0
        div     rcx
        mov     rcx, rdx
        mov     rdx, rcx
        lea     rax, [rbp-64]
        mov     rsi, rdx
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::operator[](unsigned long)
        movzx   eax, BYTE PTR [rax]
        movsx   edx, al
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-72]
        mov     esi, edx
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::operator+=(char)
        add     DWORD PTR [rbp-20], 1
.L16:
        cmp     DWORD PTR [rbp-20], 99
        jle     .L17
        nop
        lea     rax, [rbp-64]
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string() [complete object destructor]
        jmp     .L26
        mov     rbx, rax
        lea     rax, [rbp-22]
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    std::allocator<char>::~allocator() [complete object destructor]
        mov     rax, rbx
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    _Unwind_Resume
        mov     rbx, rax
        lea     rax, [rbp-21]
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    std::allocator<char>::~allocator() [complete object destructor]
        jmp     .L21
        mov     rbx, rax
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-72]
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string() [complete object destructor]
.L21:
        lea     rax, [rbp-64]
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string() [complete object destructor]
        mov     rax, rbx
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    _Unwind_Resume
.L26:
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-72]
        mov     rbx, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
        leave
        ret
secretKey[abi:cxx11]:
        .zero   32
.LC2:
        .string "Success!"
securityCheck(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >):
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 16
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], rdi
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
        mov     esi, OFFSET FLAT:secretKey[abi:cxx11]
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    __gnu_cxx::__enable_if<std::__is_char<char>::__value, bool>::__type std::operator==<char>(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)
        test    al, al
        je      .L28
        mov     esi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC2
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZSt4cout
        call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)
        mov     esi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& (*)(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&))
.L28:
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
        mov     esi, OFFSET FLAT:secretKey[abi:cxx11]
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    __gnu_cxx::__enable_if<std::__is_char<char>::__value, bool>::__type std::operator==<char>(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)
        leave
        ret
main:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        push    rbx
        sub     rsp, 40
        lea     rax, [rbp-48]
        mov     esi, OFFSET FLAT:secretKey[abi:cxx11]
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) [complete object constructor]
        lea     rax, [rbp-48]
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    securityCheck(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)
        lea     rax, [rbp-48]
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string() [complete object destructor]
        mov     eax, 0
        jmp     .L34
        mov     rbx, rax
        lea     rax, [rbp-48]
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string() [complete object destructor]
        mov     rax, rbx
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    _Unwind_Resume
.L34:
        mov     rbx, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
        leave
        ret
.LC3:
        .string "basic_string::_M_construct null not valid"

__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int):
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 16
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], edi
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-8], esi
        cmp     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 1
        jne     .L72
        cmp     DWORD PTR [rbp-8], 65535
        jne     .L72
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZStL8__ioinit
        call    std::ios_base::Init::Init() [complete object constructor]
        mov     edx, OFFSET FLAT:__dso_handle
        mov     esi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZStL8__ioinit
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev
        call    __cxa_atexit
        mov     eax, OFFSET FLAT:secretKey[abi:cxx11]
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    getSecretKey[abi:cxx11]()
        mov     edx, OFFSET FLAT:__dso_handle
        mov     esi, OFFSET FLAT:secretKey[abi:cxx11]
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string() [complete object destructor]
        call    __cxa_atexit
.L72:
        nop
        leave
        ret
_GLOBAL__sub_I_getSecretKey[abi:cxx11]():
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     esi, 65535
        mov     edi, 1
        call    __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

You can definitely see that you're no longer to naively scan the code for interesting strings, but there's more involved. You'll have to set breakpoints and check different values, and try to look through it logically to solve it. Still, in this example, the symbols are visible, which gives away a great deal of sensitive information about what the application is doing. Hiding the symbols makes bypassing the security more difficult, from what you can see.

Comment: This must be a joke, because when finding the entry point called `getSecretKey`, it's a piece of cake to reverse the assembly, besides the password at `LC0` is being "hidden" in plain-text. Java is not being compiled with `gcc` either, but with `javac`. Code signing is a whole lot more powerful than what you guys are trying to accomplish here (the impossible, based on some delusional idea).

Comment: The instruction `mov  esi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0` ...already gives it away.

Answer (score 0):

Hiding secret keys in code is not going to be really secure.  As you may have noticed DVDs and most software serial number registrations get hacked on a daily basis.  If you really want to secure something you need to use public key encryption.

Comment: Public key encryption is no solution. Just as the confidentiality of private keys must be protected, the integrity of public keys needs protection. Common mechanisms are hardware with physical tampering countermeasures, or a password-based secret key.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot, it is impossible. Any attacker who has access to the target machine would be able to disassemble your code to find it, or find the key file on the target machine, etc.

The ONLY way to ensure that the encryption key is secure, is to have it typed in manually by the user when it is needed.

Answer (score -2):

I think this is one of the biggest reasons that DVD and BluRay were cracked so quickly.  I think the only way that they could really stop the average person from being able to digitally copy home movies is if they created a medium that wasn't licensed for use on computers, and could only be used on certified players.  Would cut out the part of the market that wanted to watch movies on their computers and laptops, but would probably stop from having perfect digital rips for a little longer, and would stop the average person from being able to do it.